# Como posso retornar dados que estão dentro de arrays?

Tags: php, array

Estou usando este código para puxar características de um determinado produto:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    'key'       => '46dfg456465g4d654d65f4564dfg',
    'module'    => 'imoveis',
    'method'    => 'listar_origens' 
);

$client = new SoapClient(null, array (
    'uri'       => 'http://soap.imo.bi/',
    'location'  => 'http://soap.imo.bi/soap.dll',
    'trace'     => 'trace'
));

$res = $client->get($array);

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($res);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Uma destas características é o campo ***[field]*** o qual preciso recuperar 250 vezes pois existe 250 valores diferentes para este campo. O resultado do script é este:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [alias] => imo.DATA
            [field] => DATA
            [description] => Data cadastro
            [type] => Data
            [field_site] => 
        )
```

Ao colocar `$res[0]['field']` ele me retorna o primeiro valor que é ***DATA*** e assim por diante conforme vou mudando os valores. Quero de forma dinâmica dentro de um loop recuperar os 250 valores de uma vez. Peço auxílio!!!

Comment: Não tenho conhecimentos de PHP, mas creio que um loop resolveria essa situação, não?

Comment: Testa `foreach($res as $item){ echo $item['field']; }`

Comment: Esse resultado está completo? Ou ele continua 0,1,2...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se tens uma array que tem dentro de cada elemento uma outra array *associativa*, podes fazer um loop da primeira e dentro do loop fazer echo dessa chave do elemento da primeira array que está a ser iterada.

Exemplo:

```
echo "<pre>";
foreach($res as $item){
    echo $item['field'];
}
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta efetuar um loop, por exemplo:

**Usando FOR**

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($res); $i++){
echo $res[$i]['field'];
}
```

**Usando FOREACH**

```
foreach($res as $field){
echo $field['field'];
}
```

De ambas as maneira, ele irá resultar no valor em presente em $res[0]['field'], $res[1]['field'], $res[2]['field']...